# Copy preceding row if condition is met

Tags: r, dplyr

My data

```
set.seed(123)
df <- data.frame(loc = rep(1:5, each = 5),value = sample(0:4, 25, replace = T))
a <- c("x","y","z","k")
df$id <- ifelse(df$value == 0, "no.data", sample(a,1))
head(df)

   loc value     id
1   1     1       z
2   1     3       z
3   1     2       z
4   1     4       z
5   1     4       z
6   2     0 no.data
```

Rows for which I have no data, the `id` and `value` columns have `no.data` and `0`. For all rows where I have no data (`id == no.data` and `value == 0`), I want to copy the `value` and `id` from the preceding row.

```
    loc value   id
 1   1     1    z
 2   1     3    z
 3   1     2    z
 4   1     4    z
 5   1     4    z
 6   2     4    z
```

Something like:

```
df %>% group_by(loc) %>% mutate(value = ifelse(value == 0, copy the value from preceding row), id = ifelse(id== "no.data", copy the id from preceding row ))
```

Comment: May be you need `fill` after changing the 0 to `NA`

Comment: Please ignore the way I generated sample data in this question. The actual data I have is the one I showed as `df`

Comment: What I meant is `library(naniar);df %>% replace_with_na(replace = list(value = 0, id = "no.data")) %>% fill(value, id)`

Comment: Thank you. But this only corrects my `value` column. I also need to copy the `id` column from the previous row.

Comment: If you check the updated edited comment, it should correct it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We could replace the `0s` by `NA` and then do a `fill`

```
library(tidyverse)
library(naniar)
df %>% 
   replace_with_na(replace = list(value = 0, id = "no.data")) %>% 
   fill(value, id)
```

Answer (score 1):

Unless you have a very big dataset a simple loop should do

```
for (r in 2:nrow(df)) {
  if (with(df[r, ], id == "no.data" && value == 0)) {
    df[r, c("id", "value")] <- df[r - 1L, c("id", "value")]
  }
}
```

Comment: The solution provided by akrun is more convenient for me because my dataset is quite bigh. But thank you for your time.